# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException using java, awt and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, awt

I am developing a quiz game in java, which involves getting a series of questions from a database. The game compiles, and runs, but as soon as I click my "Test" button, I get the above error.
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PhysicsQuiz extends Frame implements WindowListener, ActionListener{

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        String user  = "root";
        String pass = "usbw";
        Connection c = null;
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/pastpapers", user, pass);
        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return c;
    }
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private Label menuheader;
    private Choice topiclist;
    private Button test;
    private Button scores;
    private Button quit;
    private Label questionheader;
    private Choice multiquestion;
    private TextField calculation;
    private TextField equation;
    public PhysicsQuiz(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        menuheader = new Label("Choose the topic you wish to revise.");
        add(menuheader);
        topiclist = new Choice();
        topiclist.add("Mechanics");
        topiclist.add("Materials");
        topiclist.add("Waves");
        topiclist.add("DC Electricity");
        topiclist.add("Nature of Light");
        add(topiclist);
        test = new Button("Test!");
        add(test);
        test.addActionListener(this);
        scores = new Button("View previous scores on this topic");
        add(scores);
        scores.addActionListener(this);
        quit = new Button("Quit");
        add(quit);
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        addWindowListener(this);
        setTitle("Physics Quiz");
        setSize(250, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void Test() throws SQLException{
        String topic = topiclist.getSelectedItem();
        remove(topiclist);
        remove(test);
        remove(scores);
        remove(quit);

        question[] questions = new question[10];

        for(int j=0;j<questions.length;j++){
            try{
                Connection c = getConnection();
                Statement st = c.createStatement();
                int random = rand.nextInt(33);
                System.out.println(random);
                String sqlcontent = "SELECT QuestionContent FROM question WHERE QuestionTopic = '" + topic + "' AND QuestionID = " + random;
                ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(sqlcontent);
                try{
                    while (rs1.next()){
                        questions[j].content = rs1.getString(1);
                        System.out.println(questions[j].content);
                    }
                } finally {
                    rs1.close();
                }
                String sqltype = "SELECT QuestionType FROM question WHERE QuestionTopic = '" + topic + "' AND QuestionID = " + random;
                ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery(sqltype);
                try{
                    while (rs2.next()){
                        questions[j].type = rs2.getString(1);   
                        System.out.println(questions[j].type);
                    }
                } finally {
                    rs2.close();
                }
                st.close();
                c.close();
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<questions.length;i++){
            if(questions[i].type.equals("Multiple Choice")){
                questionheader = new Label("Question " + i + " : " + questions[i].content);
                multiquestion = new Choice();
            }
            if(questions[i].type.equals("Calculation")){
                questionheader = new Label("Question " + i + " : " + questions[i].content);
                calculation = new TextField();
                equation = new TextField();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error. Cannot get results from query");
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PhysicsQuiz app = new PhysicsQuiz();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String action = e.getActionCommand();
        if(action.equals("Test!")){
            try{
                Test();
            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        if(action.equals("View previous scores on this topic")){

        }
        if(action.equals("Quit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { }
}
```

And here is my full error message:

```
E:\Documents\GitHub\COMP4-Project>java PhysicsQuiz
Connected to database
2
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PhysicsQuiz.Test(PhysicsQuiz.java:70)
        at PhysicsQuiz.actionPerformed(PhysicsQuiz.java:116)
        at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
        at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:75)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:75)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I would appreciate all help, as this is a project with a deadline. Thanks!

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly where the exception is thrown. Something is null at that line.

Comment: The stack trace implicates line 70 of PhysicsQuiz.java, which occurs in function `Test()`.  I'm too lazy to count for you, so what line is that?

Comment: Since the output shows two printlns (connected and the random integer) and doesn't show the question content you know where the problem is. In this case you declared the questions array but didn't actually allocate a new question before setting a field on it. That is likely your null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response, John Bolinger .Line 70 is questions[j].content = rs1.getString(1);

Comment: Thanks JimW, that seemed to work initially, but now it goes to about 6 items in the array, then the error repeats.